# Script not diplaying in JSP

Tags: jsp, scriptlet

Only the "We are Creating a String "is displayed.Whatever I am giving inside script is not displaying.Please give me solution

This is my jsp page

```
<html>
          <head>
            <title>How To Create a String</title>
          </head>  <body>
            <h1>We are creating a String</h1>
            <%
                String create = "We have create a String";
                %>
                <h2><%out.println(create);%></h2>
          </body>

    </html>
```

Thanks
 Narayanan

Answer (score 0):

Just include these codes in the beginning of the file,

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have tried but no luck till now.I displaying this jsp file in the outbound of the Mule ESB server,When i see the view source of this page I am able to see my complete file.Server not able to process scriplet code.

Comment: I have deployed your jsp in Tomcat server, it works fine. May be you having problem with your server, check with some other sample jsp files in your server.

Comment: Thanks it working fine,have used ajax which streams static data and now changed to Jetty